# Macro populating dynamic array (from userform checkbox selections)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have an array (I will have 4 of these) that is populated based on the user selecting between 1 and 4 checkboxes.

My question is: why can't I populate the array directly from looping through the checkboxes and finding the selected ones?

This doesn't work:

```
Dim chkBox As Control
Dim sectArr() As Variant
Dim s as long
s = 0

For Each chkBox In Me.SectorsFrame.Controls 'Sector-level frame
If TypeName(chkBox) = "CheckBox" And chkBox.Value = True Then
   sectArr(s) = chkBox.Caption
   s = s + 1        
End If
Next
```

This works:

```
Dim chkBox As Control
Dim sectArr As Variant, sectStr As String
sectStr = ""

For Each chkBox In Me.SectorsFrame.Controls 'Sector-level frame
    If TypeName(chkBox) = "CheckBox" And chkBox.Value = True Then
        sectStr = sectStr & "|" & chkBox.Caption
    End If
Next
sectStr = Right(sectStr, Len(sectStr) - 1)
sectArr = Split(sectStr, "|")
```

I get either "subscript out of range" (with parenthesis on the array) or type mismatch (without parenthesis).

I'd like to not deal with strings and then chopping them up and filling my arrays with them (do I have to deal with them??). I don't understand enough about this to know what I can and can't do, though.

My next 3 arrays can have 1 - 6 options, and a two-dimensional array with multiple options possible.

=====================EDIT 2/3/2016 @ 1800z==========================

This looks promising - I took what you said, [PeterT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4717755/petert), and played with it some, coming up with the following (probably still clumsy) code:

```
Dim chkBox As Control
Dim sectArr() As Variant
Dim sec As Long

 sec = 0
    For Each chkBox In Me.SectorsFrame.Controls 'Sector-level frame
        If TypeName(chkBox) = "CheckBox" And chkBox.Value = True Then
            ReDim Preserve sectArr(sec)
            sectArr(sec) = chkBox.Caption
            sec = sec + 1
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: My guess is it breaks if the first checkbox is false so your array doesn't get filled starting from `0`.

Comment: @findwindow been testing with first one as true - hadn't tried the first one being un-checked (false) so far. That's a good thing to remember though (I wouldn't have thought of that immediately, and would've had to troubleshoot it later).

Comment: You need to `Redim` the array to set the index bounds first. That's why you're getting the "subscript out of range" error. If you're only storing the captions for the checked controls, you probably have to loop through the controls and count the number of checks first, then `Redim`, then capture the captions.

Comment: @PeterT I'll keep that in mind, thank you. As a follow-up to this: if I loop through them to get the number of checked boxes, is there a way to avoid looping through them again to assign said boxes to the array? I'm trying to keep things smaller and faster, and I (think I'm) adding time looping/counting looping/adding vs just using the string and plugging that into the array (or am I wrong about that?).

Comment: Alternatively to populating an array, you can use a `Collection` or a `Dictionary` and get it done in a single loop.

Comment: @PeterT thank you for the input - I edited my response above with the result of your comment. TYVM